# How can I capture multiple return values in a call to MATLAB's arrayfun?

Tags: arrays, matlab, return-value

I have a function that takes an image as an argument and produces a label and a score as a result. I occasionally want to quickly test over a (cell) array of images, and the most convenient way I know to do this is using `arrayfun`. This works fine for getting the labels my function produces, but I would really like the output to be a list of `[label score]` cells.

I could write a wrapper around my function that captures both values and returns them as a cell matrix, and then call that wrapper within `arrayfun`, but it seems like this is a common enough idiom that there should be a way to work with multiple return values more conveniently. Is there? (Perhaps a standard convenience function already exists that can do this? Sort of like the opposite of `deal`...)

Comment: Could you provide some pseudocode demonstrating exactly the behavior you're hoping for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get your output as two matrices by using built-in syntax:

```
  [A, B, ...] = arrayfun(fun, S, ...);
```

For example:

```
function [y,z]=foo(x)
     y= x*x;
     z = x + 10;
end
```

And then run the function :

```
[A,B] = arrayfun( @foo, magic(5))
```